# How to avoid duplicate insert of dynamic values in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, duplicates, notin

I want to write a query to insert dynamic values if they or NOT present therein already. So far I have tried this.

```
INSERT MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes (aml_code, aml_desc)

    SELECT 'NRA', 'Non-Resident Alien'
    UNION
    SELECT 'DOM', 'Resident Alien'
    FROM MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes t1
    WHERE t1.aml_code NOT IN (SELECT t2.aml_code from MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes t2)
```

But this is returning only upper select (which is already present in the table). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any special reason you need to use a UNION?

Comment: @OtávioDécio How else can I insert the dynamic values? I do not have them stored in any table where I can use the column name.

Comment: Are you assuming the `WHERE` is applied to the result of the `UNION` instead of just the second select statement?

Comment: @hatchet Even if I apply where condition separately, it did not solve purpose. I think I cannot control insertion of non duplicate info by using INSERT into SELECT... for hardcoded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem you're having is that in your version the WHERE clause was only applying to the last Select in the UNION clause

TAke the records you want

```
 SELECT 'NRA' AS aml_code, 'Non-Resident Alien' AS aml_desc
    UNION 
 SELECT 'DOM' AS aml_code, 'Resident Alien' AS aml_desc
```

And then wrap them up as a subquery (aliased as [src] in the example) you can then check which ones don't have matching keys in the destination table (aliased as [dst])

```
INSERT MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes (aml_code, aml_desc)
SELECT src.aml_code, src.aml_desc
(
    SELECT 'NRA' AS aml_code, 'Non-Resident Alien' AS aml_desc
    UNION 
    SELECT 'DOM' AS aml_code, 'Resident Alien' AS aml_desc
) src
WHERE src.aml_code NOT IN (SELECT dst.aml_code from MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes dst)
```

Personally I'd do it with a left join like this but it's up to you

```
  INSERT MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes (aml_code, aml_desc)
SELECT src.aml_code, src.aml_desc
FROM
(
    SELECT 'NRA' AS aml_code, 'Non-Resident Alien' AS aml_desc
    UNION 
    SELECT 'DOM' AS aml_code, 'Resident Alien' AS aml_desc
) src
LEFT JOIN MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes dst
ON dst.aml_code = src.aml_code
WHERE dst.aml_code IS NULL
```

both would work but if you had to match on multi-column key you'd need to use the join method

Answer (score 0):

You are HARDCODING the values of the resultset, wrapping quotes means a literal value, you must want the COLUMN name.

```
SELECT 'DOM', 'Resident Alien'
```

You need to have your SELECT like this:

```
SELECT T1.ColName, T1.AndAnotherColName
....
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is the point. I have to insert a harcoded value in the table only when I know it is not there already. I am not sure if/how this can be done.

Comment: you need to show data examples, your question is not well written.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting static data which have no relation to the tables `MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes`. So your insert query can be simplified like below

```
INSERT MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes (aml_code, aml_desc)
VALUES ('NRA', 'Non-Resident Alien'),('DOM', 'Resident Alien')
```

**EDIT:**

Then you need to check whether those values do exist or not and accordingly do the insertion as shown below

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(select 1 from MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes where aml_code in('NRA','DOM') 
and aml_desc in ('Non-Resident Alien','Resident Alien'))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes (aml_code, aml_desc)
VALUES ('NRA', 'Non-Resident Alien'),('DOM', 'Resident Alien')
END
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul but how can I ensure that I am NOT inserting duplicate records?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement can be used for your needs. It succinctly does what you're trying to do.

```
MERGE MTB_AML..tb_aml_codes AS dest
USING (
    -- place here whatever you want to insert if not already present
    -- I'm using something like what you have in your question since 
    -- that's your example
    SELECT 'NRA', 'Non-Resident Alien'
    UNION
    SELECT 'DOM', 'Resident Alien'
) AS src
ON dest.aml_code = src.aml_code
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (aml_code, aml_desc)
    VALUES (src.aml_code, src.aml_desc)
;
```